# MRTG does not give precise value or converts wrong?

Tags: snmp, monitoring, system-monitoring, graph, mrtg

By example:
I have SNMP response value `59757296`, passed to MRTG via conf ("business as usual").
The value is in bytes (I checked specs of the target device plus web interface of device confirms).

In theory I should be getting "58356.7" KB in MRTG graph but I am getting "59682.5 KB".
I know it's average over 5 minutes and value varies a bit (I have manually monitored the value and it randomly goes up/down 200KB over 5 min). Perhaps MRTG divides by 1000 and not by 1024 for KB value?

relevant MRTG setting:

```
kMG[mem]: b,K
ShortLegend[mem]: B
```

Comment: if its bandwidth, multiplier should be 1000. for capacity the multiplier is 1024, so use `kilo[mem]: 1024`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/doc/mrtg-reference.en.html), MRTG uses 1000 as the `kilo` multiplier by default. You can change it as follows:

```
kilo[mem]: 1024
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

`Options[mem]: bits`

It does change "kilo" multiplier and other things.